# mutable/immutable объекты

Tags: java

Читаю про mutable/immutable объекты
У неизменяемых объектов много полезных свойств. Но можно выделить два, которые характерны практически для всех immutable-объектов:

1) Неизменяемые объекты можно реализовать значительно проще, чем изменяемые.
2) Неизменяемые объекты можно свободно использовать одновременно из разных нитей.

У меня несколько вопросов, пожалуйста прошу если вы отвечаете и вам не трудно ответьте пожалуйста мне по пунктам, заранее спасибо :)

**1)** **Как понять объекты можно реализовать значительно проще?**

**2) Правильная информация или нет? - Неизменяемый объект - это такой объект, чье внешнее видимое состояние не может измениться после его создания. Классы String, Integer и BigDecimal в библиотеке классов Java являются примерами неизменяемых объектов - они представляют отдельное значение, которое не может измениться в течение жизненного цикла объекта.**

**3) Какие mutable/immutable объекты бывают кроме классов String (StringBuilder, StringBuffer), Integer, BigDecimal? Просто названия я хочу их посмотреть**

**4) Неизменяемые объекты можно свободно использовать одновременно из разных нитей.
Нитей это потоков? Это синонимы?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значительно проще, потому, что когда объект не может измениться в принципе:

- Отпадает необходимость дополнительных проверок, синхронизации записи, поддержания инварианта класса после изменения полей.
- Отпадает необходимость копирования разделяемых данных.

Кроме того

- Создается возможность для кеширования экземпляров, как явного, так и по усмотрению компилятора.
- Становится возможной более агрессивная оптимизация.

Список immutable классов в стандартной библиотеке пополняется постоянно, но более менее полный список попытались привести в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30005285).

Свободно использовать возможно и нельзя, потому, что неизменяемый объект вполне может содержать изменяемые поля, но в общем случае использовать immutable объекты в многопоточных приложениях гораздо безопаснее, а в ряде случаев и совершенно безопасно.

Comment: А почему написаны классы оболочки, а не примитивные типы? Ведь это разные вещи, просто я как замечал примитивный тип int тоже неизменяемый

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Написаны классы, не обязательно оболочки. int - не класс вовсе. Вообще список привел просто чтобы был, потому, что во внешних библиотеках таких классов не счесть, и используются они повсеместно как в java, так и в других языках, возможно даже чаще чем изменяемые.

Comment: Я знаю что int это не класс, но int относится же к immutable объектам? Просто сделал пример и получилось как со String поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Такие типы просто не классифицируются в терминах `mutable`/`immutable`, так же как число 1 не простое и не составное. `int` не передается по ссылке, только по значению, так что с одной стороны переменная типа `int` может менять содержимое, в этом смысле он `mutable`, но если мы взяли int например из массива, а после модифицировали в массиве значение, то взятое нами не изменится. в этом смысле он `immutable`.

Comment: Вы не знаете как перейти в чат обсуждений? Я просто хочу вам небольшой пример скинуть, у меня там вопрос один

Comment: Дополните вопрос или создайте новый, или скиньте сюда ссылку на pastebin/ideone/и т.д. Чат можно создать вручную, ссылка внизу страницы, а можно дождаться, когда система предложит перенести дискуссию в чат :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93443/discussion-between---and-extrn).